# How can I DRY up my Rspec/Capybara suite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In my suite I have this in many `it` blocks:

```
let(:user) { create(:user) }
let(:plan) { Plan.first }
let(:subscription) { build(:subscription, user: user ) }


it "something" do
  subscription.create_stripe_customer
  subscription.update_card valid_card_data
  subscription.change_plan_to plan
  login_as user
end
```

How could I DRY this up so I don't have to duplicate all these lines across many files?

Comment: You can't have `let` statements in `it` blocks and `let` statements in `describe` blocks apply to all nested `it`s, so there is no need to repeat them.  Please share your code.

Comment: My point is that I use the subscription to login_as user part in multiple files across my spec suite. I want to dry up those lets and boilerplate.

Comment: Oh,sorry, I missed the "files" part of the question (I was thinking "many it blocks").

Comment: So, you're seeing that the three `let` lines and the three lines within the `it` are all recurring, right?  Are you familiar with "shared examples"?

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a method like

```
def prepare_subscription
    subscription.create_stripe_customer
    subscription.update_card valid_card_data
    subscription.change_plan_to plan
end
```

And in your it block like so:

```
it "something" do
  prepare_subscription
  login_as user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You ain't checking value for that spec so it always green.

If you need prepare some data before test then you could put that code into helper and call it when needed in (for example) `before` block.

If you need check spec passing again and again then you could use [shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples).